# Should I provide application-wide dependencies in module or component?

Tags: angular

I wanted to ask community about Angular good practice regarding providing application-wide dependencies, should I do it in module or component?

As I am thinking proper way is to provide it in module but documentation has some two misleading statements.

In one:

> Application-wide dependencies
>   Register providers for dependencies used throughout the application in the root application component, AppComponent.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#app-wide-dependencies

they are saying that in AppComponent but here:

> Should I add application-wide providers to the root AppModule or the root AppComponent?
>   Register application-wide providers in the root AppModule, not in the AppComponent. Lazy-loaded modules and their components can inject AppModule services; they can't inject AppComponent services. Register a service in AppComponent providers only if the service must be hidden from components outside the AppComponent tree. This is a rare use case.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-root-component-or-module

that in AppModule.

Comment: Could you quote the relevant parts of the documentation that you feel conflict? Links should supplement a question, not be required reading.

Comment: I haven't found the first text block you quoted int the document you linked to.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer fixed

Comment: Still can't find the text inside the linked page using the browsers search feature.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer This link should take you to proper place on website you don't have to use search... look for "Application-wide dependencies" header

Comment: I see. The first two words are the title. To me this looks like outdated content from the time when `NgModule` didn't yet exist. I'm sure the proper way to provide application-wide is using `NgModule` in `AppModule` or a feature module added to `imports: [...]` of `AppModule`.